# How can I use IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2 to connect to a database for a Scala application

Tags: mysql, database, scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to develop a database management tool in Scala through the IntelliJ IDE, but am having trouble even making a simple connection.  All the tutorials I have seen are telling me to go to the Data Sources tool window, but I have not been able to find that menu option where I am being told to look.  My Windows->Tool Windows menu does not have a data sources option (I am using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2).

Is this tool in a different place in this version, or is there another simple way to manage a database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have this window, too. According to the [IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/data-sources-tool-window.html) as well as [IntelliJ Wiki](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/NetBeans_FAQ#How_do_I_configure_a_JDBC_database_connection_in_IntelliJ_IDEA.3F.2A) it is available in Ultimate edition of IntelliJ only. What edition do you have?

Comment: *sigh* I suppose that makes sense.  I have the free version.  I figured out how to make the connection without it though, by importing a mysql-connector.jar to my java folder

Comment: Yes of course it is possible to write programs that connect to a database with the free version or even without an IDE, too. Only the database GUI is missing in this case.